# parsing deeply nested xml in sencha touch

Tags: javascript, html, sencha-touch, extjs

I'm trying to parse a xml file and I'm having problems with a really simple nested tag but every example I have seen just takes the easy way of reading not nested xml tags, or plainly changing the xml (I can't do that). So my question is: in Sencha touch 1.1, how can I configure the model to load just one property which is nested inside a couple of tags? I tried this:

```
    Ext.regModel('article',{
    fields: [
        {name:'Headline',type:'string'},
        {name:'Summary',type:'string'},
        {name:'Body',type:'string'},
        {name:'Thumbs',mapping:'Photos > Thumbnail'}
    ],
});
```

and this would be an xml item:

```
<Headline>
blah blah blah
</Headline>
<Body>
blah blah blah
</Body>
<Summary>
blah blah
</Summary>
<Photos>
<Photo src="big_image_link" width="400" height="276"/>
<Thumbnail src="little_image_link" width="110" height="80"/>
</Photos>
</item>
```

the model is parsing the headline, summary and body just fine, the problem comes with the Photo and Thumbnail inside the "Photos" tag, I have tried with associations in every way I've seen documented but it didn't work in any case, I'm just interested in the Thumbnail src property, I don't know why it is THAT hard.

**edit:** I changed the code to reflect how I got to the 'Thumbnail' tag when I edited a local copy of the xml to be like

```
<Thumbnail>image_link</Thumbnail>
```

But now I need to access the 'src' and I don't know how the mapping should change from

```
mapping:'Photos > Thumbnail'
```

And I've tried: Photos > Thumbnail, Photos > Thumbnail.src, Photos > Thumbnail > src, Photos > Thumbnail @src, and a couple more ways, still no answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up parsing the xml with plain js and adding each object to the store, hopefully sencha touch 2 will have a working xml reader on it's final release.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems right. You only need to change `mapping:'@src'` to `mapping:'src'` i.e. with out the `@` character.

Comment: sadly it doesn't work either, I'm editing the code to show how I got a little bit closer