# Loading nested xml into sencha-touch-2.1

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.1

I am trying to load a partially nested xml file (small sample below) from a legacy system into a nestedlist view or navigation view in st 2.1 and having no luck. I'm not sure if I can just use a tree store or maybe multiple stores one for folders and then another for the procedures?

I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13301105/nested-list-multiple-layouts/13349251#13349251) and [solution](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#vsY1o) but I don't see how it would handle the nested aspect.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated, I fear my computer may not survive my rath for much longer.

```
<TOC_Data>
    <FolderInfo>
        <Sequence>1</Sequence>
        <Description>Sample Procedures</Description>

        <ProcedureInfo>
            <Metadata>302</Metadata>
            <OdfId>a</OdfId>
            <Number>1</Number>
            <Title>PRO1</Title>
            <ProcType>1</ProcType>
            <FileExtension>xml</FileExtension>
        </ProcedureInfo>
    </FolderInfo>

    <FolderInfo>
        <Sequence>5</Sequence>
        <Description>Styles</Description>

        <FolderInfo>
            <Sequence>6</Sequence>
            <Description>Checklist></Description>

            <ProcedureInfo>
                <Metadata>85</Metadata>
                <OdfId>b</OdfId>
                <Number>2</Number>
                <Title>PRO2</Title>
                <ProcType>1</ProcType>
                <FileExtension>xml</FileExtension>
            </ProcedureInfo>

            <ProcedureInfo>
                <Metadata>119</Metadata>
                <OdfId>c</OdfId>
                <Number>3</Number>
                <Title>PRO3</Title>
                <ProcType>1</ProcType>
                <FileExtension>xml</FileExtension>
            </ProcedureInfo>
        </FolderInfo>
    </FolderInfo>
</TOC_Data>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a duplicate of [parsing deeply nested xml in sencha touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401968/parsing-deeply-nested-xml-in-sencha-touch)

You need proper field "mapping" configs. The mappings are Ext.DomQuery paths.

- http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?103110-Nested-XML-mapping-how-to
- http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.DomQuery
- http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-mapping

Comment: Thanks will have a look at those links now and see if I can make any head way. I don't think its the same as the example you quote as I need to map it into a tree store and also the level of nesting is unknown before hand. I'm beginning to think I need to use association in with the models, a folder model which has many folders or many procedures or similar.